# Eclipse does not find SQLite JDBC in classpath. BuildPath is already customized. But why?

Tags: java, sqlite, web-services

I have a method with which I want to create a table with 5 attributes. However, if I want to run the createTable method, I get the error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
But I have already added the SQLite Jar to the BuildPath? 
Here is my code:

```
   public static String createTable() {
      Connection c = null;
      Statement stmt = null;

      try {
         Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
         c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
      //   System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

         stmt = c.createStatement();
         String sql = "CREATE TABLE Fahrrad "+ 
                        "(ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
                        " Standort TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                        " LeihStatus BOOLEAN NOT NULL, " + 
                        " Modell CHAR(50));"; 



         stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
         stmt.close();
         c.close();

      } catch ( Exception e ) {
         System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
         System.exit(0);
      }
      // System.out.println("Table created successfully");




      return "SQL Datenbank mit dem Namen Fahrrad und den Attributen ID, Standort, LeihStatus und Modell erfolgreich angelegt.";
```

}

And here is a picture of the build PAth of my project:

[Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drdlb.png)

Why am I getting the error even though I added the external jar to the Build Path?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to the tab "Order and Export" and check the entry of the jar.